# Docker 'container ls --all' not working after installation

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to run and check docker container after installation but i'm not able to, plus all other commands displays the following output

> Saved file tree to doc-filelist.js
>   Copied JS to doc-script.js
>   Compiled CSS to doc-style.css

Any assistance will be highly appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker run hello-world not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40675829/docker-run-hello-world-not-working) title/command isn't the same but the output is the same, so hopefully the answer will help.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance.