# Angular 9 and docker why docker is only returning doc folder instead of building the app?

Tags: angular, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to upload image of my angular 9 application into `Docker hub`. I have docker extension already installed in my visual studio code, and I connected it to my username and added my account password.

Then, I ran the following command to install docker globally:

`npm install -g docker`

At the root path of my project, I've created `Dockerfile` having the following script:

```
# Stage 1
FROM node:latest as node
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build --prod

# Stage 2
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=node /app/dist/myproject /usr/share/nginx/html
```

And then I tried:

```
FROM 13.13.0-alpine3.10 as build-step
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json /app/
RUN npm install
COPY . /app/
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:1.17.10-alpine as prod-step
COPY --from=build-step /app/dist/myproject /usr/share/nginx/html
# COPY /dist/myproject /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

I then tried to build my application using:

`docker build --rm -f "Dockerfile" -t myproject:latest "."`

And I've got the following response instead of building the app:

> Saved file tree to doc-filelist.js
>
> Copied JS to doc-script.js
>
> Compiled CSS to doc-style.css

And a `doc` folder has been created. But nothing else has been done.

I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40675829/docker-run-hello-world-not-working) on stack overflow using `docker.js` but I don't think it is the solution I want to build a docker image and upload to docker hub and run it from there.

Comment: `FROM 13.13.0-alpine3.10`. Looks like you are trying to reference a `node` image here? Should it be: `FROM node:13.13.0-alpine3.10`? Also the answer you are referencing points out that you are calling `docker.js` instead of a true Docker Engine. Try installing Docker Engine here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/.

Answer (score 0):

You're not installing the Docker Engine you want with that npm command.
This is how you install Docker Engine: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install. After that you can try to build your Dockerfile.

Also your image name seems wrong: `FROM 13.13.0-alpine3.10`. Looks like you are trying to reference a node image here? Should it be: `FROM node:13.13.0-alpine3.10`?

Comment: I will download the engine, check it and gets back to you. Thanks. Yes it should be `node:13.13.0-alpine3.10`

Comment: There is no way to just upload the dist folder into docker hub and test it there?

Comment: without downloading a 1GB file?