# I can't run docker on CMD: saved file tree to doc-filelist.js Copied JS to doc-script.js Compiled CSS to doc-style.css

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, docker-run

I don't know why, but I've installed docker using npm (i've installed the app too).
I'm on a mac air M1
And when running any docker command (run), i've got this message (example with rabbitMQ):

```
docker run -it --rm --name rabbitmq -p 5672:5672 -p 15672:15672 rabbitmq:3.11-management
Saved file tree to doc-filelist.js
Copied JS to doc-script.js
Compiled CSS to doc-style.css
```

Please help me !

Comment: I don't think you've actually installed Docker the container tool.  It's a precompiled Go binary and not something you could install using `npm`.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61266373/angular-9-and-docker-why-docker-is-only-returning-doc-folder-instead-of-building/76065933#76065933

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, in the official NPM registry, someone registered the name 'docker' for their own personal project.  All it does is generate some documentation.  The official page to the project gives a 404 link so this project is probably long dead.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/docker

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a package named 'docker' installed.

Use `npm uninstall -g docker` and try again.