# Any docker command shows the exact same 3 lines of compilation code

Tags: macos, docker, command-line-interface

Descriptive title I know.

I am on a Mac with an M1 chip and I've installed docker. Now I've tried installing it using Brew and the GUI version built for the M1. The only thing is that any and all docker command shows the following in all locations. I also tried running it from the docker file location to no avail:

```
MacBook-Pro-2 docker-test % docker help

Saved file tree to doc-filelist.js
Copied JS to doc-script.js
Compiled CSS to doc-style.css
```

Or with Docker ps:

```
MacBook-Pro-2 docker-test % docker ps

Saved file tree to doc-filelist.js
Copied JS to doc-script.js
Compiled CSS to doc-style.css
```

And honestly at this point I am stumped as to what the issue might be. So what I've tried is to reinstall it with the built in tool which opens just fine, but the same issue keeps occuring.

Has anyone encountered a similair issue? I think it might be something to do with the path variable but tbh I am fairly new to MacOS and have not used that a lot.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE** It worked in bash for a bit but it now shows the same as it did on ZSH.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker run hello-world not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40675829/docker-run-hello-world-not-working)

Comment: It does! Thanks!

Comment: Hope the answers help anyone with this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75665489/21351199